# How do I default a name in a list without SP designer

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a list with a People/Group field I wish to default it to a Team mailbox email address.

Is this possible without SP designer ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. The person/group field doesn't come with a default value field, and even if you were to create an InfoPath form for the list, the default value function is disabled. You may be able to populate it with JavaScript, but you'd still have to resolve it using the check user control manually as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

@Oc3Lot is correct.  Options I can think of are:

1. Small workflow that populates the value
2. Use JavaScript to set the value
3. With InfoPath form you can use a rule to populate the default value

Of the 3 - the Workflow is pretty easy to get started with and you only really need the single task.

The JavaScript would probably be 2nd (my opinion b/c I don't like InfoPath and XSLT all that much) - you can use jQuery or something more specific like this from SPServices library  http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPFindPeoplePicker  (Marc has a ton of tutorials on how to use it)

InfoPath will require some calls to the profile service and some custom XSLT - you can find references on the web, but I think you will find it easier with one of the other two approaches unless you are already comfortable with InfoPath.

Comment: Hi @Oc3LotI have looked a t workflows...but I do not see any that involve 1 task.  I see a 3 state, Approve, Feedback, etc....

Comment: I looked at workflows and I do not see any that involve task ?